# Combining Multiple Worksheet_Calculate Subs

Tags: excel, vba

I have learned that it's not possible to have more than Worksheet_Calculate subs in one module/sheet. Is it possible to simply combine these subs into one sub? It can't be as simple as copying and pasting one sub below the other? I have these two subs displayed below that are trying to accomplish the same action but the conditions that they need to meet are different. How can I combine these two? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

   If Sheets("Ledger").Range("AC2").Value < 0.4 Then

   'find new last row
   newLastRow = Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row()

   'delete new last row
   Intersect(Range("ABCDEF"), Rows(newLastRow)).Delete
   End If
End Sub


Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

   If Sheets("Ledger").Range("L4").Value < 0 Then

   'find new last row
   newLastRow = Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row()

   'delete new last row
   Intersect(Range("ABCDEF"), Rows(newLastRow)).Delete
   End If
End Sub
```

Edit #2:

After placing the second subroutine in the first subroutine....not only am I getting an "excel has run out of resources error" but also a rRun-time error '13': Type mismatch" error. It is pointing to the "If Sheets("Data").Range("I2").Value < 0.4 Then" line in another sheet module for some reason. Here is the code from that sheet. It's a simple msgbox macro.

````
```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Sheets("Data").Range("I2").Value < 0.4 Then

'display messagebox error
MsgBox "Green Investments Must Comprise 40% of Portfolio", vbRetryCancel, "Error!"
End If
````

End Sub

Comment: Move everything inside the second subroutine into the first subroutine, after the `End If`.

Comment: Hi BigBen. When you mean everything, do you mean including Sub Worksheet_Calculate line for the second subroutine as well?

Comment: No... "everything inside" meaning everything from `If ... End If` inclusive.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements

Comment: For some reason when I move everything from the second sub into the first sub and I try to get the value of range L4 to be < 0....I get that pesky error where it says that "excel has run out of resources."

Comment: I've also tried eliminating the first sub (which works on its own) and only include the second sub I have listed in a sheet and I receive a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error. And for some strange reason it takes me to a line on another sheet called "Data." I'll show the code in the body of this post in an edit.

Comment: Please someone help!

Comment: So I got the code to work. I created a new worksheet and no longer have the "resources" issue. Weird!